# Placement of HTTP Headers in VirtualHost Containers?

Tags: http-headers, virtualhost

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header always set Referrer-Policy same-origin
```

VirtualHost has port `80` and port `443` instances. Are any of the listed headers forbidden in `80` or `443` vhosts? Can and should I put them in both? NOTE: I'm redirecting port `80` to `443`. If headers are considered before the redirection occurs, I presume they don't need to be put inside 80 port vhost.

If you spot syntax errors or unnecessary usage of `always` and `set` conditions feel free to correct me or recommend alternatives.

Comment: welcome to serverfault.com, please update the question by reading [ask]

Comment: Thank you! I originally posted this question here and someone said I should transfer it to Webmasters.